# Show that limit of $g(x) = 0$ when $x$ goes to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

$f(x)$ is differentiable for $x > 0$, and
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)= 0\,.$$
We have a new function $g(x) = f(x+1) - f(x)$.

Prove that:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x) = 0\,.$$

I thought about using Lagrange for $g(x)$ for every $x > 0$. But it seems not going pretty well. Any ideas?

Comment: Are yoou sure you want to prove $$\lim_{x\to\infty}g'(x) = 0,$$ or $$\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x) = 0$$ instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  question on derivatives seems trivial. Let me try to answer $$\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = 0\,,$$ instead. The [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) on $f$, since it is differentiable, states that, for all $x> 0$,  there exists a $c_x\in ]x,x+1[$ such that:
$$f'(c_x) = \frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{(x+1)-x}  = g(x)\,.$$
Hence as $f'\to 0$, you will get $g\to 0$ as well.

Answer (score 2):

$g$ is differentiable, and $g'(x)=f'(x+1)-f'(x)$ so taking limit as $x\to\infty$, as RHS converges to $0-0$, LHS must converge to $0$ as well!

Answer (score 2):

Notice that
$$g'(x)=f'(x+1)\cdot 1-f'(x)=f'(x+1)-f'(x)$$
by the sum and chain rules.

Also,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)=0\qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad \lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x+1)=0$$
Thus, by the properties of limits,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} g'(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\Big(f'(x+1)-f'(x)\Big)=\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x+1)-\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)=0-0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
g'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{h}\Big(\big[f(x+h+1)-f(x+1)\big]-\big[f(x+h)-f(x)]\Big)\\
=f'(x+1)-f'(x).
$$
Then you can follow the one by Pedro.